# Indexing a JSON file with multiple documents in elastic search

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am new to elasticsearch i want to index a JSON file and perform search queries from elasticsearch

How can I index this json and perform queries to get value if i pass parameter as "field3.innerfield" : "someval"

I have tried indexing this file with **helpers.bulk** and search but it returns all the fields instead of a selected field.

Below is the JSON sample

```
[
    {
        "id": "someid",
        "metadata": {
            "docType": "value",
            "otherfield": " ",
            morefields
            .
            .
        },
        "field1":"value1",
        "field2":"value2,
        "field3": [
            {
                "innerfield": "someval",
                "innerfield1":[
                    "kind of a paragraph"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "field4": [
            {
                "innerfield": "someval",
                "innerfield1": "kind of a paragraph"
            }
        ],
    },
    { again the format repeats with different id but same fields
    },
    {
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks clarity however what I understood is that you want to fetch values from its key for a nested json. You can do that in the following way as shown below.
Parse it multiple times and make the required changes as per your need.

```
import json
data = data.apply(lambda x: json.loads(json.loads(x).get("metadata","{}")).get("doctype") if x else None)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying . My bad i have not specified that i want that in elasticSearch. I'm looking for elastic search indexing and search query for the same.